# Changing css checkbox over to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

The left image I replicated using javascript.

code https://jsfiddle.net/27kbd6uv/

The right one is the css checkbox version.

code https://jsfiddle.net/7eqL9ty8/

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEWvc.png)

I messed up somewhere in the code, but I don't understand what I did wrong.

Everything is the same, so it should look the same visually, **but they don't when both are off.**

The **css checkbox version looks darker** when off compared to the javascript version.

They should both look the same when off.

```js
(function manageCurtain() {
  "use strict";
  
  
  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    hide(cover);
    const switchbox = document.querySelector(".switchbox");
    switchbox.classList.add("slide");
  }

  const cover = document.querySelector(".button");
  cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #fafcff;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, transparent, #afb5bf), linear-gradient(transparent, #d3d8e0);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.switchbox {
  background-color: black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 195px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 1px 2px black, inset 0 2px 2px -2px white, inset 0 0 2px 15px #47434c, inset 0 0 2px 22px black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  perspective: 700px;
}

.switchbox.slide .button {
  transform: translateZ(20px) rotateX(25deg);
  box-shadow: 0 -10px 20px #ff1818;
}

.switchbox.slide .button .light {
  animation: flicker 0.2s infinite 0.3s;
}

.switchbox.slide .button .shine {
  opacity: 1;
}

.switchbox.slide .button .shadow {
  opacity: 0;
}

.switchbox .button {
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);
  transform-origin: center center -20px;
  transform: translateZ(20px) rotateX(-25deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background-color: #9b0621;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#980000 0%, #6f0000 30%, #6f0000 70%, #980000 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.switchbox .button::before {
  content: "";
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 30%, #650000 75%, #320000) 50% 50%/97% 97%, #b10000;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.switchbox.slide .button::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: linear-gradient(#650000, #320000);
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: translateY(50px) rotateX(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 50px 8px 0px black, 0 80px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.switchbox.slide .light {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: light-off 1s;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#ffc97e, #ff1818 40%, transparent 70%);
}

.switchbox .dots {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(transparent 30%, rgba(101, 0, 0, 0.7) 70%);
  background-size: 10px 10px;
}

.switchbox .characters {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(white, white) 50% 20%/5% 20%, radial-gradient(circle, transparent 50%, white 52%, white 70%, transparent 72%) 50% 80%/33% 25%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.switchbox.slide .shine {
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);
  opacity: 0.3;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(white, transparent 3%) 50% 50%/97% 97%, linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), transparent 50%, transparent 80%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)) 50% 50%/97% 97%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.switchbox.slide .shadow {
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 70%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@keyframes flicker {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  80% {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes light-off {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="switchbox">
  <div class="button">
    <div class="light"></div>
    <div class="dots"></div>
    <div class="characters"></div>
    <div class="shine"></div>
    <div class="shadow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/bd7r5afj/

Comment: Yes, but with checkbox removed from the code.

Comment: And when they are turned off, they both have to look the same visually. That's where I was having issues with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JavaScript version, you have this CSS:

```css
.switchbox.slide .shine {
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);
  opacity: 0.3;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(white, transparent 3%) 50% 50%/97% 97%, linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), transparent 50%, transparent 80%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)) 50% 50%/97% 97%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.switchbox.slide .shadow {
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 70%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

When the switch first loads on the page, the class `slide` doesn't exist (looks like you're applying this in your JavaScript later), so this the `.shine` and `.shadow` styles are not being applied. You need to apply the these styles even when the `slide` class is off, like this:

```css
.switchbox .shine,
.switchbox.slide .shine {
  /* .. existing styles .. */
}
.switchbox .shadow,
.switchbox.slide .shadow {
 /* .. existing styles .. */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're adding the classes but never removing them so I added a bit of js code and refactor it so it does it.
Edit: Modified the css cause in my last post I forgot to copy that part.

```js
const switchbox = document.querySelector(".switchbox");
(function manageCurtain() {
  "use strict";


  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
    switchbox.classList.add("slide");
  }

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
    switchbox.classList.remove("slide");
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    if (cover.classList.contains("hide")) {
      show(cover)
    } else {
      hide(cover);
    }
  }

  const cover = document.querySelector(".button");
  cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #fafcff;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, transparent, #afb5bf), linear-gradient(transparent, #d3d8e0);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.switchbox {
  background-color: black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 195px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 1px 2px black, inset 0 2px 2px -2px white, inset 0 0 2px 15px #47434c, inset 0 0 2px 22px black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  perspective: 700px;
}

.switchbox.slide .button {
  transform: translateZ(20px) rotateX(25deg);
  box-shadow: 0 -10px 20px #ff1818;
}

.switchbox.slide .button .light {
  animation: flicker 0.2s infinite 0.3s;
}

.switchbox.slide .button .shine {
  opacity: 1;
}

.switchbox.slide .button .shadow {
  opacity: 0;
}

.switchbox .button {
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);
  transform-origin: center center -20px;
  transform: translateZ(20px) rotateX(-25deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background-color: #9b0621;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#980000 0%, #6f0000 30%, #6f0000 70%, #980000 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.switchbox .button::before {
  content: "";
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 30%, #650000 75%, #320000) 50% 50%/97% 97%, #b10000;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.switchbox.slide .button::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: linear-gradient(#650000, #320000);
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: translateY(50px) rotateX(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 50px 8px 0px black, 0 80px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.switchbox.slide .light {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: light-off 1s;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#ffc97e, #ff1818 40%, transparent 70%);
}

.switchbox .dots {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(transparent 30%, rgba(101, 0, 0, 0.7) 70%);
  background-size: 10px 10px;
}

.switchbox .characters {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(white, white) 50% 20%/5% 20%, radial-gradient(circle, transparent 50%, white 52%, white 70%, transparent 72%) 50% 80%/33% 25%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.switchbox.slide .shine {
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);
  opacity: 0.3;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(white, transparent 3%) 50% 50%/97% 97%, linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), transparent 50%, transparent 80%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)) 50% 50%/97% 97%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.switchbox.slide .shadow {
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);
}

.switchbox .shadow {
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(transparent 70%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@keyframes flicker {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes light-off {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="switchbox">

  <div class="button">
    <div class="light"></div>
    <div class="dots"></div>
    <div class="characters"></div>
    <div class="shine"></div>
    <div class="shadow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```